# Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL POST Request

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am trying to get my POST request to work via flask. 
It GETs the data from a .py document (which works fine. It is being displayed the way I want to in a table)
But would not let me POST to it. I always get the error:

*Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.*

Console: "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 -

My JavaScript Code:

```
  function addUserList() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", '/api/users', true);
    xhttp.onload = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 201) {
        alert("user created")
      }
      else{alert("Error")
    }
  };

    data = {fname: "Henry", lname: "Ford"}
    stringdata = stringify(data)

    console.log("function add user triggered")

    xhttp.send(stringdata);

}
```

and my main app.py:

```
def getUserList():
   if request.method =='GET': 
       return jsonify({"data": userlist})
   if request.method =='POST': 
       repobj = json.loads(request.data)
       user = repobj['fname']
       user1 = repobj['lname']

       newid = userlist[-1]["id"]
       newuser = {"id":newid +1,
                  "avatar":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg",
                  "first_name":user,
                  "last_name":user1,
                  "email":"george.bluth@reqres.in",
                  "job": "Doctor"}
       userlist.append(newuser)
       resp = make_response("", 201)
       return resp
```

Right now I am trying to hardcode the fname and lname to see if its working.

**I am new to Flask!**

**Thank you loads!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.py where you define the function `getUserList`, in the parentheses you must add: `methods="GET", "POST"`. Flask automatically handles the method `GET` but you can only use the method`POST` if you specifically say that the function can handle it. It will end up as: `def getUserList(methods="GET", "POST"):`